# How to redirect with custom parameters?

Tags: symfony, silex

I'm building a form. When the user submit the form, data are saved into the db, then the user is redirected to the same form with:

```
return $app->redirect('/admin/edit/user/' . $message);
```

The message variable is a message about the success or failure of the DB job.

But this solution doesn't suit me best... Is it possible to do the same with passing the `$message` variable as a POST parameter ? I don't want it appears into the URL...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route_name', array('param1' => 'foo', 'param2' => 'bar')));
```

But... look at this:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages

Comment: Does it need an other symfony component than symfony routing?

Comment: `return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'));` === `return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('homepage'));`

`$this->generateUrl('homepage)` === `$this->get('router')->generate('homepage');`

So, if you just want to generate links, just you just need router. If you also want to redirect, you need to use RedirectResponse.

http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.html#generate()

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.html

Comment: As far as I understand this shows parameters in the URL?