# Symfony 5 - A problem with the form to registrate a credit card with MangoPay

Tags: php, forms, symfony, if-statement, mangopay

I'm trying to register a credit card with MangoPay.

I've installed the `mangopay/php-sdk-v2` package.

To register a credit card, it needs three steps.

1. Create a token of the card
2. Post card info (using a url created by the token) that will render a string that start with `data=`
3. Add the registered card to the MangoPay user

```
// ProfilController.php 

   /**
     * @Route("/payment/{id}", name="payment")
     * * @param int $id
     */
    public function payment(Request $request, ApiUser $ApiUser, $id): Response
    {           
            $returnUrl = "";

            $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
            $userId = $user->getIdMangopay();
            $registration = $ApiUser->Registration($userId);
            
            if($request->request->count() > 0){
                $payment = new PaymentMethod(); 
                $payment->setName($request->request->get('name'));
                $payment->setCardNumber($request->request->get('cardNumber'));
        
                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $entityManager->persist($payment);
                $entityManager->flush();

                $registrationCard = $ApiUser->RegistrationCard($registration, $request);

                $returnUrl = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                $returnUrl .= '/profil';
            }
            
            return $this->render('home/payment.html.twig', [
                    'CardRegistrationUrl' => $registration->CardRegistrationURL,
                    'Data' => $registration->PreregistrationData,
                    'AccessKeyRef' => $registration->AccessKey,
                    'returnUrl' => $returnUrl,
            ]);
    }
```

The `Registration` and `ResitrationCard` functions come from the `ApiUser` file:

```
// ApiUser.php

    public function Registration($UserId)
    {
        $CardRegistration = new \MangoPay\CardRegistration();
        $CardRegistration->UserId = $UserId;
        $CardRegistration->Currency = "EUR";
        $CardRegistration->CardType = "CB_VISA_MASTERCARD";
        $Result = $this->mangoPayApi->CardRegistrations->Create($CardRegistration);
      $this->registrationInfo = $Result;
      $this->CardRegistrationUrl = $Result->CardRegistrationURL;

      return $Result;
    }

    public function RegistrationCard($CardInfo)
    {
      $cardRegister = $this->mangoPayApi->CardRegistrations->Get($CardInfo->Id);

      $cardRegister->RegistrationData = $_SERVER['QUERY'];
      
      $updatedCardRegister  = $this->mangoPayApi->CardRegistrations->Update($cardRegister);
    
      return $Result;
    }
```

I'm able to create the token of the card and get the `data=` string, but the problem is that I cannot do the last step.

It seems that I cannot enter into the `if` statement, so it doesn't register the card on the database and I cannot update the card information (3rd step).

The `returnUrl`, I can simply put it outside of the `if` statement to make it works, but I want to change it only if the form is valid.

How can I fix the statement? Why doesn't it enter into the `if`?

Comment: Hi, why d'ont you use the common form validation process of Symfony (using the Form bundle) ? https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#handling-form-submissions

If the 'if' statement is not passed, then there is a probleme whith you condition ;)

Comment: When you create a token, you will have to put some of its key to another website `homologation-webpayment.payline.com`. This post is made with some specific keys (`data`, `accessKeyRef`, `cardNumber`, `cardExpirationDate` and `cardCvx`) taken by the attribute `name` of the input. When using the common form, the `name` attribute wil be like `name="registration_card[data]"` and the homologation site will read it as a 'bad' key as I found out recently. 
I don't know how to change the condition nor how to change the `name` attribute

Comment: With Javascript, I've been able to change the `name` attributes, but now the returnUrl doesn't work. It will leave my website to go the one who make the `data=` string, while it should gave me the `data=` string on the url of my website as query

Comment: Note that `$this->userRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id])` is the same as `$this->userRepository->find($id)`, and as said before, you shoulduse `$form->isSubmitted()` instead of `if($request->request->count() > 0)` to check if the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use the regular form validation process of Symfony, and let me know if this helps.

To do this, you need to customize the input name attribute for it to match the payment API config.

In your Type class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        // ...
        ->add('new-input-name-goes-here', TextType::class, [
            'property_path' => '[data]'
        ]);
}
    
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return '';
}
```

Comment: It works, it has changed all the `name`. But with changing the type of the form, now it doesn't work the `returnUrl`, while it shows the `data=` on blank page and it won't give it in the URL like it did before.

Comment: You mean that you need to get a response with custom params after the form was submitted ? You can use a redirection under the `if($form->isSubmitted())` of your controller and pass parameters to it. For passing params to a redirection, please refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191580/how-to-redirect-with-custom-parameters#answer-27191684 Please tell me if that helps or not

Comment: Not exactly, I want the the reponse on the URL as query, so I can retrieve it.
Maybe it's just me who doesn't know how to makes it work. I've put under the `if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())` a return with the redirect.
I've tried different ways as I saw on the links given and as I understood, like: `return new RedirectResponse($returnUrl);`, `return $this->redirectToRoute($this->generateUrl($this->generateUrl($returnUrl))` or `return redirect($returnUrl)`, but they don't even do the redirection.

Comment: What is the exact URL you want to redirect to? Past it here so it will be easier for me to determine the best way to do it.

Comment: Please verfy that you use the correct way of dealing with forms in Symfony. I have detailed it here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71942460/convert-post-request-to-doctrine-entity/71961314#71961314 You can copy the example controller and modify it to your needs.

Comment: It's a bit complex. I have to send to `https://homologation-webpayment.payline.com/webpayment/getToken` these informations: `data`, `accessKeyRef`, `returnURL`, `cardNumber`, `cardExpirationDate` and `cardCvx`.
When not given the `returnUrl`, it will send you to its website (`https://homologation-webpayment.payline.com/webpayment/getToken`) rendering on its page the `data=`, but if you give a `returnUrl` (in my case is 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/32'), it will send you to the page within the key and the `data=` will be rendered as a query on the URL.

Comment: Well from what i understand, it doesn't seem so special. I just can't see any redirection to the external page `https://homologation-webpayment.payline.com/webpayment/getToken` in you controller. Most often when dealing with APIs like you do, we send a JSON request and wait for the call back (asynchronous code): https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response